# How to change propertygrid grid row line color wpf?

Tags: winforms, xceed

I use xceed.wpf.toolkit.propertygrid in my project. But grid row line is not clear to see. [image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS0XI.png)

How can i change grid row line color and thickness to clear visibilty.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use EditorTemplateDefinition , for example a template for City and email with yellow background  :

```
<xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition TargetProperties="City,Email">
          <xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition.EditingTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Background="Yellow" Text="{Binding Value}" />
             </DataTemplate>
          </xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition.EditingTemplate>
       </xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition>
```